# Agendar Tarefas com Timer

Tags: java

### Situação:

---

**Descrição:** Tenho esse `Timer` para executar minhas tarefas em um determinado período de tempo de acordo com os `seconds` informado.

---

**Problema:** Ao executar o programa a tarefas começa ignorando os segundos informado, depois que a tarefa é executada pela primeira vez os tempo é respeitado.

---

**Necessidade:** Quando o programa é iniciado ele deve esperar os segundos que informado "30", "60", "1200" e depois a tarefa deve começar.

---

```
    public executarTarefas(int seconds) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new limparQuarto(), Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), seconds * 1000);   
}
```

---

**Observação:** Esse método executa a tarefa `limparQuarto()` que é apenas um exemplo, se alguém souber chegar a "necessidade" desgraço.

Comment: Prezado Eduardo, minha colocação resolveu seu problema? Se sim, poderia por gentileza marcar a pergunta como respondida, para auxiliar na organização?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro de `schedule` refere-se à primeira execução, portanto ele deve ser o período informado mais a soma dos segundos desejados, conforme referência abaixo:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

```
public void schedule(TimerTask task,
            Date firstTime,
            long period)
```

> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning at the specified time. Subsequent
> executions take place at approximately regular intervals, separated by
> the specified period.
>
> In fixed-delay execution, each execution is
> scheduled relative to the actual execution time of the previous
> execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage
> collection or other background activity), subsequent executions will
> be delayed as well. In the long run, the frequency of execution will
> generally be slightly lower than the reciprocal of the specified
> period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is
> accurate). As a consequence of the above, if the scheduled first time
> is in the past, it is scheduled for immediate execution.
>
> Fixed-delay execution is appropriate for recurring activities that
> require "smoothness." In other words, it is appropriate for activities
> where it is more important to keep the frequency accurate in the short
> run than in the long run. This includes most animation tasks, such as
> blinking a cursor at regular intervals. It also includes tasks wherein
> regular activity is performed in response to human input, such as
> automatically repeating a character as long as a key is held down.
>
> Parameters:
>
> task - task to be scheduled.
>
> firstTime - First time at which task is to be executed.
>
> period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
>
> Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if firstTime.getTime() < 0, or period <= 0
>
> IllegalStateException - if task was already scheduled or cancelled, timer was cancelled, or timer thread terminated.
>
> NullPointerException - if task or firstTime is null